# How to download macports packages separately?

Tags: macports

I would like to download an extensive list of `macports` packages through an accelerator and install them offline.

Using the following command, the list of packages required was obtained,

```
 port echo rpedof:<pkg_name> and not installed
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed beyond that. I could painstakingly find the port for each one, but there far too many.

All I require is to have an output in the form of lists of urls for each dependant package. I'll be able to do the rest with download scripts.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What would the accelerator speed up?

Comment: @Mark, terminal accelerators generally downloads packages faster than the average download speed of MacPorts. I use <code>axel</code> for general use and <code>aria2c</code> when there are too many redirects and when ftp passwords are to be supplied.

Comment: What would it accelerate in a macports download?

Comment: @Mark: Well, MacPorts downloads src. files for each port (usually in tar.gz or tar.bz2) from several available repos. The most used would be http://distfiles.macports.org/. You would only know the exact possible url locations once it tries to fetch the package (this can also be done offline). But this only lists the available urls for the package in the argument -- not its dependencies. You can try fetching the full path for each dependency package 1 by 1, but this isn't efficient when you have too many dependencies. You'd rather allow MacPorts to do its usual thing rather than to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `port fetch rdepof:$pkgname and not installed` to trigger only downloading source code. Given that you want to use download accelerators, that probably doesn't do what you want.

If you just want to get the URLs for downloading, see `port distfiles rdepof:$pkgname and not installed` and parse its output. Note that you may have to deal with ports fetching source code from Git/Subversion/etc.

You can use a script I wrote a while ago as a starting point; it already parses the output correctly and initiates the download (using curl), however it downloads every URL in the mirror list, not only one of them. The script is at https://trac.macports.org/browser/contrib/port-checkmirrors/port-checkmirrors.